Beamer: Latexmk Warnning about Package CTex for Package hyperref
When I try to compile my own tex file by latexmk, this warnning in topic has occured.
I use the following configuration:
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

The Warnning message is:
Package hyperref: Option `driverfallback' has already been used,
(hyperref)  setting the option has no effect.

RMK: When I switch to xelatex, this warnning has already dismiss. 
So, where the problem comes from? CTex or latexmk or others?

You seem to use pdflatex when compiling with latexmk and ctex uses then equivalent of \hypersetup{driverfallback=dvipdfmx} if hyperref has already been loaded. That is senseless as you can't change the driver or or the driverfallback with \hypersetup. Report it to the ctex maintainer.

Thanks for your answer. I will report this problem.
